# Strust2 datetimepicker - months and days are displayed in numbers not text

Tags: plugins, dojo, struts2

Running the following piece of code on IE6 displays the datepicker component but the months and days are displayed in numbers (months 1-12, days 1-7):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<sx:head />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Struts 2 example</h1>
<sx:datetimepicker name="date1" label="Format (dd-MMM-yyyy)"
displayFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy" value="todayDate" dayWidth="wide" language="el_GR"/>
<br>
<br>
<sx:datetimepicker name="delivery.date" label="Delivery Date" displayFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"  />
</body>
</html>
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me workround/resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is your problem, or exactly how struts maps these properties, but Dojo uses dashes to specify locale variants like the XML spec (e.g. el-gr) rather than el_GR which is the Java notation.